# Let $xy|(x^2+y^2+1)$. Prove that $\frac{x^2+y^2+1}{xy}=3$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $x,y -$ positive integers, such that $xy|(x^2+y^2+1)$. Prove that
>   $$\frac{x^2+y^2+1}{xy}=3.$$

**My work so far:**

1) If $x=y=1$ then $\frac{1^2+1^2+1}{1}=3$

2) Let $x=1$ (or $y=1$) $\frac{1^2+y^2+1}{y}=k \Rightarrow y^2-ky+2=0$

$D=k^2-8=m^2 \Rightarrow (k-m)(k+m)=8 \Rightarrow k=\pm3, m=\pm1 $, but $k\in \mathbb N \Rightarrow k=3$

3) $x,y>1$

$xy|(x^2+y^2+1) \Rightarrow x^2+y^2+1=kxy, k \in \mathbb N$

$D=k^2y^2-4y^2-4$

Here I need help...

Comment: I think I saw this somewhere before..

Comment: To reduce to Pell's equation. The formula is there. for example, such use.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8603/markov-hurwitz-equation

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping#Constant_Descent_Vieta_jumping) has a full solution of this problem using the technique called Vieta jumping.

Comment: @DietrichBurde exact duplicate.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Yes, I know. The system writes "Possible duplicate" . The wikipedia link has also exactly this example for Vieta jumping.